# Rendering SVG element in React is not allowing me to render any other HTML elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I'm trying to render the following in React:

```
      <div>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox={`0 0 ${width} ${height}`}>
          {data.map((row, rowIndex) => {
            return row.map((column, colIndex) => {
              return (
                <Rectangle
                  key={`${row}.${column}`}
                  callBack={handleClick}
                  rectDimension={rectDimension}
                  separator={separator}
                  column={colIndex}
                  row={rowIndex}
                  colorToggle={column}
                />
              );
            });
          })}
        </svg>
        <p>Test paragraph</p>
      </div>
```

where `<Rectangle>` is the following:

```
      <rect
        onClick={trigger}
        fill={colorToggle ? "black" : "white"}
        x={(rectDimension + separator) * column}
        y={(rectDimension + separator) * row}
        height={rectDimension}
        width={rectDimension}
      />
```

When I build the page that uses this component, I'm getting only the SVG, but not the `<p>` element below it. I've tried using flexbox to put the two elements in a column, and that hasn't worked. I've also tried rendering the `<p>` without the SVG above and it comes out fine on its own. Anyone have any ideas for what's going sour?

Comment: Try to inspect the exclosing DIV (F12 in Chrome). Do you see the paragraph element in the DOM tree? Maybe it's hidden behind the SVG?

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky yeah I just looked in the DOM tree, it is there. I just changed the flex-direction on the enclosing `<div>` to row, and I see only the paragraph (actually two copies of the paragraph) and not the SVG.

Comment: and instead of the self-closing ``<rect />`` a closing tag ``</rect>`` ??

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Tried that. doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Since you don't get the ``<p>`` but do get the SVG I suspect a syntax error in the SVG.. Missing quotes? wrong attribute names? Check every byte in the SVG . Or start with an empty SVG and built the content element by element.